# Ensure parsed org.w3c.dom.Document is DTD valid after changes

Tags: java, xml, dom, dtd

I have a document `org.w3c.dom.Document` parsed from a stream. The XML has a DTD entity declaration, so document creation fails when the stream is invalid according to the dtd.

Now I need to make changes to the document and want it to be still DTD valid when it is serialized and saved.

Of course this can be done by serializing and parsing it again, but that seems quite a bit of overhead that is not even needed.

What is the proper way (ideally by only using the org.w3c.dom api) to implement this ?